# Reference request: Do any papers on odd perfect numbers approach the problem using the following equation?

Tags: reference-request, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This question has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228649).)

Do any papers on [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) approach the problem using the following equation?

> $$N - (q^k + n^2) + 1 = \sigma(q^{k-1})(q-1)(n+1)(n-1)$$
>   where $N={q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form.

I do know that the equations
$$\sigma(n^2) = {q^k}\cdot\left(\frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}\right)$$
and
$$n^2 = {\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}}\cdot\left(\frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}\right)$$
are true.

From these two equations, we can prove that
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}.$$

Here, $\gcd(a,b)$ is the *greatest common divisor* of $a$ and $b$, and $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of the divisors of $x$.